# Ventricular Filling : Systole or Diastole?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, human-anatomy, human-physiology, anatomy

As the Blood goes down from the Atrium to the Ventricles:

- The Tricuspid Valve ( Right Atrioventricular Valve)
- Bicuspid Valve (Mitral Valve )

The **atrial pressure** is **INCREASES** WHEN ATRIA ( THE **ATRIA CONTRACTS** AT THIS STAGE/**ATRIA SYSTOLE**) Thus:

- **fills the ventricles** with blood ( blood goes down from the atria to the ventricles)
- The Tricuspid/ Bicuspid valves **OPENS** since there is a **higher pressure of Atria than the Ventricle**

Questions:

- Is the Ventricular Filling, (When Blood from Atria fills the Ventricles) itself a **DIASTOLE or SYSTOLE**
- So during the Ventricular Diastole
- Ventricular Filling is Diastole?? ,
- Is it when *VENTRICLES* are filled with *blood* :

  > it increases THE PRESSURE IN IT SO THAT IT MAKES A
  >   (** VENTRICULAR DIASTOLE /VENTRICULAR CONTRACTION **)

I also saw in here that:
" The P wave represents the atrial electrical depolarization. This phase is ventricular diastole. During filling, pressure within the right atrium increases, pushing blood across the AV valves into the right ventricle."

I'd also like to clarify:

> > Shouldn't it be  WHEN IT FILLS THE VENTRICLE is filled,
> >      *THE PRESSURE GOES LOW* in *atria* gradually within the???
> >     I get it that the **atrium** has a ***HIGHER PRESSURE BEFORE FILLING*** and it makes the ***(TRICUSPID AND BICUSPID) valve OPEN***

Kindly clarify through diagrams and steps, I'm somehow confused. Thank you!
You can kindly watch this short clip of video and this may help me clarify things:

http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0072495855/student_view0/chapter22/animation__the_cardiac_cycle__quiz_1_.html

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/cardiac-cycle

Answer (score 1):

Ventricular diastole is a period in [cardiac cycle](https://www.thoughtco.com/phases-of-the-cardiac-cycle-anatomy-373240) during which the ventricles are filling with blood. During this period, the atria are contracting and the ventricles are relaxed.

The diastole consist of this: atrioventricular valves open, atria contract (atrial systole), blood flows from the atria to the ventricles, the atrioventricular valves close.

When the term systole or diastole is used without saying is it atrial or ventricular, it means it is ventricular. For example, systolic blood pressure is the blood pressure during ventricular systole and diastolic during ventricular diastole.

Comment: According to what i've read and during **ventricular filling** the valves open because of there is  lower pressure in the ventricles, however the atria contracts  **only on the later stage of ventricular filling** it does not take most part of the **ventricular filling**

Comment: There are detailed graphs available, if you are interested in the exact timing of all events of the cardiac cycle.